# Reading RAW image files as GDI+ bitmaps

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gdi+, dng

Is there a good way to read RAW image files (especially Canon CR2 and Adobe DNG files) as GDI+ bitmaps that is reasonably fast?

I found an example running under WPF that would read an image using any installed image codec and then display it in an image control. And I modified this example to create a GDI+ bitmap by writing the WPF image to a MemoryStream and creating the Bitmap from that. But this process is slow! Horribly slow! Opening a simple image takes around 10 seconds on my computer. This solution also requires references to the WPF assemblies and that doesn't feel right, especially not since I would like to run the code in an ASP.NET project.

There are programs that will do batch conversions of the images, but I would prefer converting the images dynamically when requested.

So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft.

Our [DotImage Photo Pro](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage) product can do this.  If you want to try to do it yourself, look into wrapping the opensource DCRaw or look at how Paint.NET does it (I think there's a RAW plugin for it)

Comment: DCraw: http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/

Answer (score 3):

The DotImage Photo Pro component worked well, but I had a problem extracting the preview image from raw files using it. It is also outside my budget for this project.

But, I found the code for a RAW plugin for Paint.NET [here](http://paintdotnet.forumer.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=3759) and it was quite simple to adapt to my needs. The plugin runs the DCRaw executable usign `Process.Start` and reads its output from the `StandardOutput` stream. Quite simple and fast! :-)

Edit:

The link to the plugin doesn't work anymore, but here is the code I used to extract the images. The following code extracts the jpg-preview stored in the raw file. If you want the full image you should remove the -e argument. But be aware that for some cameras you will get a ppm-image that GDI+ cannot read.

```
public Stream GetImageData(string inputFile, string dcRawExe)
{


    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(dcRawExe)
    {
        Arguments = "-c -e \"" + inputFile + "\"",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };

    var process = Process.Start(startInfo);

    var image = Image.FromStream(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream);

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);

    return memoryStream;
}
```

Also, you will need a copy of DCRaw. I used the DcrawMS.exe from this site: http://www.insflug.org/raw/Downloads/

Comment: Does/can this read the EXIF data too?

Comment: No, but there are other command line tools that will extract the exif. Try to google for "dcraw exif"

Comment: The site you linked to is down. Any chance of posting the code in here to help further seekers? :)

Comment: http://www.centrostudiprogressofotografico.it/en/dcraw/ new link

Comment: For windows forms applications, can we return `Image.FromStream...` directly (without copying to `MemoryStream`)?

Comment: No I don't think so. We use the MemoryStream to get a copy of the Image that we can use elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a C# port of dcraw, albeit rather old (v8.88) which could be adapted to include newer Canon models:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/dcrawnet/

**EDIT :**
I just got it to work in my own project for reading EXIF data from RAW files:

1. Open project properties and set *Output Type* to *Class Library*.
2. Recompile.
3. Add a reference to the DLL in your own project.
4. Add `using dcraw;` at the top.
5. Declare these lines of code:

   ```
   DcRawState state = new DcRawState();
   state.inFilename = filename;
   state.ifp = new RawStream(filename);


   Identifier id = new Identifier(state);
   id.identify(state.ifp);
   ```

Now check out all the goodies inside **state** (assuming your RAW file is supported and didn't cause an exception ;)