# Is there a good .NET library for reading RAW files?

Tags: .net

We're writing a .NET-based app to read images including RAW files.  Is there a good library we can use?  Perhaps a wrapper around dcraw or libraw?  License-wise, LGPL is fine but GPL wouldn't be.

Comment: [I asked a similar question some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227604/reading-raw-image-files-as-gdi-bitmaps). The option I ended up using was running DCRaw and capturing the output into a GDI+ Bitmap object. It works well and it isn't too slow.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't yet, but there might be soon, based on the information in the [question I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455018/extending-the-list-of-supported-image-formats-in-gdi), which is more aimed at extending the support to all GDI+ applications.

Pretty much all other options I've come across involve wrapping dcraw (there's example code for a plugin for Paint.Net)

EDIT:
Probably should also mention the obvious (well it is now I've found out about it); [Windows Imaging Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737408.aspx) is supported by at least Canon have a [downlaodable codec for it](http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0032411.asp?model=), which will give you support in a WPF application

EDIT2:
It doesn't have to be a WPF application itself, just needs v3+ of the Framework to pull in the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace fro BitmapFrame/etc.

Comment: RAW codecs from Nikon (http://www.nikonimglib.com/nefcodec/), Sony (http://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/www/download/vista_raw/) and Olympus (http://www.olympus.co.jp/en/support/imsg/digicamera/download/software/codec/) are also available for download.

Comment: BTW, working link for Canon codec: http://www.usa.canon.com/consumer/controller?act=ModelInfoAct&fcategoryid=225&modelid=15206

Answer (score 1):

The ImageMagick library, which can read almost every image format, has a .NET wrapper which you could use.

Answer (score 1):

There is http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcrawnet/ but it's only in alpha