# Mono Compatible RAW Image Decoders

Tags: c#, image-processing, mono

I would like to be able to decode and preview all manner of RAW image files from within an application written in C#/Mono.  Preferably something that is fully implemented in C# as I need to to run cross-platform and would rather not have to have platform specific binaries just for the raw decoding...
Anyone know of any libraries that do this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, as on the windows platform, you can just use the vendor supplied RAW codecs.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491015/is-there-a-good-net-library-for-reading-raw-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at DCRaw (http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/).

While its not written in C# it is available for windows/linux and the source is available. Its worked really well for the RAW files I converted.