# Convert raw images to bitmap in c#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

My code currently looks like this:

```
if (fe == "CR2")
{
    Image img = null;
    byte[] ba = File.ReadAllBytes(open.FileName);
    using (Image raw = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(ba)))
    {
        img = raw;
    }
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(img);
    pictureBox1.Image = bm;
    statusl.Text = fe;
}
```

When I open a RAW image the program stops and Visual Studio says:

> Parameter is not valid: Image raw = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(ba))

Please help! How can I get a RAW file to show in a PictureBox ?

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Runtime error, compilation error...

Comment: ba is a `byte[]` while MemoryStream expects a ? hmm

Comment: GDI+ does not support RAW format. Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227604/reading-raw-image-files-as-gdi-bitmaps) for suggested alternative approaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the bitmap like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
```

or without using bitmap:

```
 this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
```

Example WPF:

```
BitmapDecoder bmpDec = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(origFile),
BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.None);
BitmapEncoder bmpEnc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
bmpEnc.Frames.Add(bmpDec.Frames[0]);
Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmpEnc.Save(ms);
Image srcImage = Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: I got another exception "Out of memory." What did i do wrong?`if (fe == "CR2")
                {
                    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
                    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                    statusl.Text = fe;
                }`

Comment: What size is the image?

Comment: OutOfMemory can be caused by: The file does not have a valid image format.
--
GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

Comment: I tried with .arw (Sony raw image) and .cr2 (Cannon raw image) and they are photos made with the camera.

Comment: Image doesn't understand .cr2 or arw files. Convert them to .JPG or PNG / BMP etc. With WPF it is possible with BitmapDecoder and requires codec with WIC support to be installed

Comment: What is WPF? How do i convert raw images to .bmp in c#?

Comment: Normally Windows Forms is used to represent UI but WPF another way to create an UI app. It is commonly used to build more advanced UI apps and advanced drawing. http://www.wpftutorial.net/WPFIntroduction.html

Comment: So how do WPF help me?

Comment: Yes, it may resolve your problem but only when you have the Raw codes. See my anwser for code for a sample which may work.

Comment: I see but where do i get the raw code and what do i do with them? "BitmapDecoder" could not be found...

Comment: BitmapDecoder does only exists in WPF,  so you  must create a new WPF project. http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/codecs/

Comment: Ok i will try it out but how do i use the raw codes after i have them?

Comment: I cannot help you further, i don't have experience with WIC codes and using BitmapDecorder.

Answer (score 3):

You're actually disposing an Image by specifying `using (Image raw = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(ba)))` later assigning the `Disposed` instance of image to `picturebox` which leads to this exception. To make to work you've to either don't dispose or clone the image.

```
Bitmap raw = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(ba) as Bitmap;
pictureBox1.Image = raw;
```

Or simply Clone

```
using (Image raw = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(ba)))
{
    img = raw.Clone() as Bitmap;
}
```

Both of the above should work

Comment: @user2635745 What exception? update stacktrace and exception name

Comment: "Parameter is not valid."

Answer (score 1):

you try this code :

```
private static void SaveImageToRawFile(string strDeviceName, Byte[] Image, int nImageSize)
    {
        string strFileName = strDeviceName;
        strFileName += ".raw";

        FileStream vFileStream = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter vBinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(vFileStream);
        for (int vIndex = 0; vIndex < nImageSize; vIndex++)
        {
            vBinaryWriter.Write((byte)Image[vIndex]);
        }
        vBinaryWriter.Close();
        vFileStream.Close();
    }

    private static void LoadRawFile(string strDeviceName, out Byte[] Buffer)
    {
        FileStream vFileStream = new FileStream(strDeviceName, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader vBinaryReader = new BinaryReader(vFileStream);

        Buffer = new Byte[vFileStream.Length];

        Buffer = vBinaryReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(vFileStream.Length));

        vBinaryReader.Close();
        vFileStream.Close();
    }
```